# R: split up concatenated csv

Tags: r

I have a large data file that contains several data frames concatenated or "glued" together.

```
Wvlgth Global_horizn_irradiance
.2820E+04 .1958E-08
.2840E+04 .3041E-05
.2860E+04 .1284E-03
.2880E+04 .6259E-03
.2900E+04 .1530E-02
.2920E+04 .4437E-02
Wvlgth Global_horizn_irradiance
.3000E+03 .5965E-02
.3200E+03 .3408E+00
.3400E+03 .6779E+00
.3600E+03 .7522E+00
.3800E+03 .8358E+00
.4000E+03 .1276E+01
Wvlgth Global_horizn_irradiance
.3800E+03 .8358E+00
.4000E+03 .1276E+01
...etc.
```

I would like to read this file in such that it is all one dataframe without the header rows:

```
Wvlgth Global_horizn_irradiance
.2820E+04 .1958E-08
.2840E+04 .3041E-05
.2860E+04 .1284E-03
.2880E+04 .6259E-03
.2900E+04 .1530E-02
.2920E+04 .4437E-02
.3000E+03 .5965E-02
.3200E+03 .3408E+00
.3400E+03 .6779E+00
.3600E+03 .7522E+00
.3800E+03 .8358E+00
.4000E+03 .1276E+01
.3800E+03 .8358E+00
.4000E+03 .1276E+01
...etc.
```

Because when I read it in now, the columns are interpreted as factors, and as.numeric gets screwed up (I need the columns to be numeric so I can graph them):

```
> as.numeric(df$Wvlgth)
  [1] 101 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

I'm not the best at math but I'm pretty sure .2820E+04 isn't actually the same thing as 101. Unless I am reading it wrong.

Comment: Your best bet is to read in the file with `readLines`, removing "headers" using regular expression or some similar functionality and then coercing everything to a data.frame. Your best bet, if you have control over it, is to force a prettier output to the csv in the first place. Perhaps there are unix tools that enable you to split file based on some line... It is trivial to import several files into R.

Comment: If you don't have any `NA` in the values, you could just load the csv with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, convert to numeric (`df$Wvlgth = as.numeric(df$Wvlgth)`) and remove the lines with introduced NA (`df = df[complete.cases(df),]`)

Comment: in case you are interested in editing the source file, this will remove all the lines containing "Wvlgth" -- > `type file.txt | findstr /v Wvlgth` This is in cmd.

Comment: @Jealie That worked, thank you! Also the headers are not always the same throughout the file, so doing any kind of find/replace would have been really difficult, unfortunately. Sorry for not mentioning that